# how to parse JSON data and show content in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I want that the object which are coming in array how to store them in object like when i use like

```
myArray.id=
myArray.name=
```

so it shuls show values

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=categories&appid=620&mainonly=true"]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a great tutorial on how to parse JSON by Matt Gallagher [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/05/classes-for-fetching-and-parsing-xml-or.html). Hope that gets you started in the right direction.

The following should display results for your code/JSON :

```
// Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

// the JSON response is an Array
NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSDictionary *dictOne = [results objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *activitiesArray = [dictOne objectForKey:@"activities"];
NSDictionary *dictTwo = [activitiesArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary *eventDict = [dictTwo objectForKey:@"event"];

NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [eventDict objectForKey:@"category"]);
```

Comment: can you give me the link of any right tutorial this is only describing fetchers

Comment: Here are some extra links : [Parsing Twitter JSON API](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api/) and [Parsing Flickr JSON API](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html)

Comment: have you seen the link which i have posted from where i am parsing

Comment: yes the link to the JSON is working so you should be able to parse it. Do you get the JSON response in your code and can you log it with NSLog() ? Next you will need to get the NSArray of activities from the JSON response.

Comment: The NSDictionary you get back in a status object in the code you posted contains a for the key `activities` an NSArray with a NSDictionary, which in itself contains for the key `event` an NSDictionary that contains the values for the key `agelimit18`. Your JSON parsing code will need to reflect the structure of the JSON code.

Comment: the point is that the JSON response you get is a tree-structure, the top of the tree is an Array A1, which contains a Dictionary D1. In this Dictionary D1 you see one key called `activities` and the value for this key is an Array A2 which contains a Dictionary D2. And in Dictionary D2 you see there is a key called `event` and the value for this key is a Dictionary D3. And in Dictionary D3 you see the key `agelimit18`. So in order to get to the value for `agelimit18` your code needs to get hold of A1, D1, A2, D2, D3. Your code is now calling `objectForKey:@"agelimit18"` on D1 instead of D3.

Comment: can you make some change in my code how to display its showing null value doing as you told

Comment: can you update the code above so i can see why it is showing null

Comment: i have updated my answer with some code to get you going in the right direction

Comment: thanks its showing listen what i want that i want that these all should store in an array and i should get from array object easily as we do in xml

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you have to look at when calling data from json, but its quite easy. First of all you should add these two lines at the top of you m-file:

```
#define kAsyncModus dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define kYourJsonURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"_THE_JSON_URL_"]
```

then, insert following part into your viewDidLoad method. "dispatch_async" has to be used with the previous defined macro (at the top) so you create a thread. Otherwise your app could crash if maybe there is no response from the server but the method keeps waiting for it.

```
// get elements of json
dispatch_async(kAsyncModus, ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: kYourJsonURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                           withObject:data
                        waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

and create a new method that will get single elements out of the received json

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json =
    [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                    options:kNilOptions
                                      error:&error];

    NSArray *results = [json objectForKey:@"_firstElementInJsonFile_"];


    NSLog(@"Results: %@", results);

}
```

for more detailes information you use the results

```
NSDictionary *specificData = [results objectAtIndex:0];
```

and it should be done.

I just explained it in the shortest way, if you want to have all facts look at following [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5).
But I'm not sure, if there is support for older devices that use < iOS5. I couldn't test it till know. If you need something like this, maybe you can look at JSONKit on Git. Maybe there is somebody who knows these detailes, would be interesting to know for me too.

Answer (score 0):

The [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) is the way to go.

However, this JSON is not valid. Tell whoever is providing the API to ensure their JSON returns are [valid](http://www.jsonlint.com).

Comment: That doesn't appear to be valid JSON according to a few different JSON validator runs. Apart from that, that is a pretty huge data return for an API call- are you sure you need to retrieve all that data at once?

Comment: yes retrieve all data  or is there any tool so that i may convert this in xml then fetch

Comment: I'd think that's not really worth it performance-wise. JSON is plenty fast and easy to parse with the SBJSon framework linked above. The issue here is that party responsible for providing the API is not generating valid JSON. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

JSONKit makes this pretty easy, might be worth considering.  And its very fast.

Comment: is JSONKit even for devices that use iOS 4.2 - 5.0?

Comment: Seems to be since they are comparing the Apple supplied NSJSONSerialization to JSONKit on the JSONKit github page readme:  https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit